# Webrowser which emulates the iPhone browser

Tags: iphone, html, web-applications, browser, webbrowser-control

On the Mac I got the iPhone Simulator but under Windows and Linux enviroments I need a webbrowser which emulates the behaviour and size of the iPhone browser. I'm not looking for a website with a frame with the iPhone screen size but an actual application. Prefably webkit based so it will behave as much like the iPhone as possible. It should also be able to send the same browser headers as MobileSafari in the iPhone and if not it should be possible to modify the headers. That could be done in a menu in the program, support plugins(which have the power to modify headers) or the progam should be opensource.

It might not exist and if not thanks anyway. However if it does that would be awesome. If you know a program which have some of the mentioned features but not all of them an no one have posted a better one feel free to post a link/the name of that browser (still better then nothing or a framed site in Safari).

tldr: iPhone like browser, same window size and headers as MobileSafari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of the following:

- **[Blackbaud iPhone Browser Simulator](http://labs.blackbaud.com/NetCommunity/article?artid=662)**
- **[iPhone Drift web browser for Windows](http://www.aviassin.com/iphonedrift)**
- **[MobiOne iPhone and Palm Pre emulator](http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/)**

So far as I can see, only the first of these actually uses Safari as the rendering engine, and it is using Safari for Windows rather than Mobile Safari, but it should be close enough I think.

Comment: Blackbaud seems nice, I as well could not find any information about what rendering engine the other two are using.

Comment: Did a quick test of blackb but had a few problems. First some times I have to restart because adress bar won't show up if I scroll or take the mouse over the menubar at top as it say. Secondly I doesn't seem to support rotated view which isn't that big of a deal. And lastly I tried going to twitter.com but for some reason it would not login. Other then that it seems promesing and the text looks like on the iPhone here unlike in the others I've tested. I don't like the stupid spaceconsuming iPhone frame but that's probably something I'll have to live with. A Linux version would be nice as well.

Answer (score 2):

try [iphonedrift](http://www.aviassin.com/iphonedrift) on windows